# cordova: external browser opened for content src

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building an very simple cordova app to do one thing: open an web url with the webview.

So I made the following change in `config.xml`

```
<content src="http://www.whatever.com">
```

It works fine with iOS emulator. Then I tried to build with `build.phonegap.com`. Installed resulting APK on my phone. But when running the application, it asks me to pick an external browser straight away.

What went wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue! It does not seem to happen all the time, but it does, for example when you set http://www.google.de - does not happen with my personal webspace which is a simple php app without any redirects or other shenanigans. Perhaps it has to do with that?

Answer (score 4):

I've played around a bit, and at least for google, adding the following to the access-origin helped:

```
<access origin="*" launch-external="no"/>
```

Perhaps this helps for you, however, I still have the issue for my own site :(

*Edit* In addition, these have solved my problem:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" launch-external="no"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

(The whitelist-plugin was installed automatically for me when I used the command line "cordova create")